# Where is $\theta$ measured from in an ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

A general point in a an ellipse is given by $(A \cos \theta, B \sin \theta)$.

Where is this $\theta$ measured from? Is it between the point and origin or the angle made by the normal at that point and the $x$-axis?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GEOMETRIC INTERPRETATION OF THE PARAMETER $\theta$ IN THE EQUATION $(acos\theta,bsin\theta)$ OF THE ELLPISE:-

It is the polar angle of corresponding point(that is the closest point sharing the same x coordinate)on auxiliary circle(circle with major axis of ellipse as diameter and center as centre of ellipse) of a point in an ellipse,in the coordinate system with origin in the centre of the ellipse.

Comment: perfect! the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Ellipse]

Radial rays inclined at angle $\theta$ to x-axis cut two concentric circles.

Lines parallel to $(x,y)$ axes
through above intersections points  again cut at each parameterized point of an ellipse.

Image copied from internet mysite.du.edu

Answer (score 0):

$\theta$ in this parameterization is not an angle that can be measured anywhere in the ellipse itself.

It is an angle in the circle you squish from the sides to *make* the ellipse, but that has no immediate interpretation as a geometric angle in the final result.

Comment: ok that explains everything. thanks